# Problem with :not() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to trigger an event if anywhere on the page is clicked except inside this one div. This is the beginning of the code:

```
$("html:not('#genre_div')").live("click", function(){
```

However, it seems that even if I click inside the `#genre_div` div, the code still gets executed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:not()` as a selector doesn't need quotes:

```
$("html:not(#genre_div)").live("click", function() {
```